# vim colors not automatically loaded (probable Vundle conflict)

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, gnome-terminal, xterm, vimrc

I've been trying to port my Windows [.vimrc](https://github.com/guilhermeasg/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) to Linux, to use on the command line (on gnome-terminal). Everything works fine, except for the colorscheme. It looks like it's loaded (`:colorscheme` returns `solarized`; `:set t_Co` returns `t_Co=256` and `:set background` returns `background=light`), but it looks ugly on my terminal. If I run any of those commands again manually (either setting `colorscheme`, `t_Co` or `background`), then the theme displays normally.

[This is the .vimrc.bundle that's sourced on my .vimrc](https://github.com/guilhermeasg/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc.bundle)

GVim also behaves normally. I tried other terminals (xterm, urxvt, screen), but none worked.

**Edit:** Looks like there's some sort of conflict with a plugin loaded by Vundle. If I comment out the `source ~/.vimrc.bundle`, the colorscheme is loaded properly.

Comment: If you post your entire .vimrc I can try and assist further.

Comment: I did, it's [here](https://github.com/guilhermeasg/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc). I just solved it yesterday. Turned out it had something to do with the fact that I had been using spf13-vim on Windows before. There were some win32 characters that were being misinterpreted by Vim.

Comment: Ah, they were ^M characters at the end of the line or somthing else?

Comment: There were `^M`s, but I'm not sure if there was anything else. I just copied and pasted my file from github and all went well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hazarding a guess that given the number of plugins you have related to colors that one is interfering. I'd comment these out and see if that resolves the issue:

```
" Bundle 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
" Bundle 'spf13/vim-colors'
" Bundle 'gorodinskiy/vim-coloresque'
" Bundle 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'
" Bundle 'skammer/vim-css-color'
```

And then enable them one at a time to isolate.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended that you set the terminal emulator’s colorscheme to use the Solarized palette.

If you are using 256 color terminal and don't use the Solarized palette you need to use the degraded 256 colorscheme. For that you have to add, before the colorscheme solarized line, the following line:

```
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
```

More information can be found on the [Solarized page](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/vim-colors-solarized#important-note-for-terminal-users)

Comment: I'm already using the solarized palette on gnome terminal, which makes it even more weird because the background goes white when I launch vim

Comment: That is weird indeed. Have you tried a GUI based `vim` to see if it is the combination of terminal + vim and not something wrong in the vim settings alone?

Comment: Yes, I have. The exact same .vimrc file (I don't have a .gvimrc)  works perfectly fine on GVim. Stranger and stranger.